# If $x=\prod^{27}_{n=1}(1+\frac{2}{n})$ then find $13x$ - Ramanujan Mathematics olmpiad 2013

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I tried this: $$x=\prod^{27}_{n=1}(1+\frac{2}{n})=(1+\frac{2}{1})(1+\frac{2}{2})(1+\frac{2}{3})\ldots(1+\frac{2}{27})=\frac{3}{1}\cdot\frac{4}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{3}\cdots\frac{29}{27}$$ Then the terms cancel out. But I am not getting the correct answer.

Comment: That first $\frac{3}{2}$ should be $\frac{3}{1}.$  Also, how does the lcm come in?

Comment: The first term is $3$, not $3/2$

Comment: The answer is [5278](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13*+product+n%3D1+to+n%3D27+%281%2B2%2Fn%29), what result did you get?

Comment: This approach works, and the answer is $13 \cdot \frac{28 \cdot 29}{1 \cdot 2} = 5278$.

Comment: I'm just curious, what kind of Olympiad is this? It seems too easy for high school maths to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, $$x=\frac31\cdot\frac42\cdot\frac53\cdots\frac{29}{27}=\frac11\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac{28}1\cdot\frac{29}1=406$$hence $$13x=13\cdot406=5278$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) or [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of arguments $29$ and $27$ : $$x={29\choose27}={29\choose29-27}={29\choose2}=\frac{29\cdot28}{1\cdot2}=29\cdot14=406\iff13x=5278.$$